# how to check the website is indexed or not indexed in google using script

Tags: php, json, google-api

using PHP script how to check the site is index or not indexed in google...and which api is used for this concept exactly..give any idea and your valuable suggestion here please..

```
<?php  

function getGoogleCount($domain) {
$content = file_get_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/' .
    'search/web?v=1.0&filter=0&q=site:' . urlencode($domain));
$data = json_decode($content);
return ($data->responseData->cursor->estimatedResultCount);
}

echo getGoogleCount('stackoverflow.com');
?>
```

this is not worked fine for me. 
 which third party url is used to find the information...

Comment: If you try the code you posted you'll get that message `The Google Web Search API is no longer available. Please migrate to the Google Custom Search API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)`

Comment: yes i got the same error...what can i do is there any way?

Comment: Like Migrate to Google Custom Search API?

Comment: How can we find the website is index or not using html_DOM_parse library is any one know